# Does php memory_limit = 1024M take up 1024MB in RAM

Tags: php, symfony, image-uploading, ini, memory-limit

I have a Symfony2 application where I am uploading photos and resizing etc. on upload using LIIPImaginebundle.

Due to the need for very large photos to be uploaded I have increased the memory_limit to 1024M but there are still larger images (eg 96Megapixel) that are being rejected.

My question is by upping the amount of memory_limit does it equate to that exact amount in ram on the server. therefore if 10 people at the same time upload these large files, would 10 x 1024 be taken up eg 10GB??

Comment: did you also check the timeout? How long does it take before it times out and is it possible to upload that file within your timeout?

Comment: I had a 60sec timeout to start but have upped that to 240sec now also which had gotten rid of that error

Comment: Are you sure that's the cause? PHP's `max_post_size` and your webserver's upload limit are also possible causes.

Comment: As @ceejayoz said - post_max_size & upload_max_filesize will also probably need to be increased.

Comment: Normally you won't require to set memory limit to such high value. File upload can be done in chunks, where post size and upload size can be set to as low as 1 ~ 2MB (thus memory limit can be set to 64M)

Comment: I don't believe it is the max_post_size or the upload_limit as the issue is not the file getting to the server but rather what is happening after the file is there. I am doing some image processing, resizing and watermarking. I can upload a 50MB photo at 14639x4251 and it is fine but a 26MB file at 12236x8128 puts it over the edge. I am then assuming it is the Megapixel size that is affecting it while processing

Comment: then I think you should add some code here in order for us to see what's wrong

Comment: @Adam I'd guess your image library turns it into a bitmap to manipulate it. I'd use something like imagemagick instead, if possible.